# parse xml and create html table pure javascript (using data block)

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom, innerhtml

Could someone spot the issue with my code ? I would like to parse my xml data into an html table but it does not work. No table is created.

My xml file called purchase

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<purchaseOrder xmlns="assoc">
  <lineItem>
    <name>Line Item 1</name>
    <price>1.25</price>
  </lineItem>
  <lineItem>
    <name>Line Item 2</name>
    <price>2.48</price>
  </lineItem>
</purchaseOrder>
```

And my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>XML Data Block Demo</title>
<script>
function runDemo() {
  var doc = document.getElementById("purchase-order").contentDocument;
  var lineItems = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS("assoc", "lineItem");
  var firstPrice = lineItems[0].getElementsByTagNameNS("assoc", "price")[0].textContent;

  var HTML = "<table><tr><th>lineItems</th><th>firstprice</th></tr>";
  var x=doc.getElementsByTagName("lineItem");
for(i=1;i<=;i++)
{
    HTML += "<tr><td>"+x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</td><td>"+x[i].getElementsByTagName("price")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</td></tr>";
}
HTML += "</table>";
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = HTML;


 }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="runDemo()";>
<object id="purchase-order" data="purchase.xml" type="text/xml"  style="display: none;"></object>
<div id="output">My table did not run</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I use the data block object method to parse xml into html see link here where my method above has been used to get the xml data [data island alternative](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_XML_Data_Islands_in_Mozilla)

Any one got any a clue on what's wrong with my code ?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

your loop looks strange:

```
for(i=1;i<=;i++)
```

why starting at 1 ? and there is no limit. Should be something like

```
for(i=0;i<=x.length;i++)
```

Furthermore, firstPrice is not used...

Answer (score 0):

These're problems you encounter:

1. The xml declaration should be:

   `<?xml version="1.0" ?>`
2. You should set the object tag's inline style as:

   `style="visibility: hidden"`
3. Your code must be run on a server to avoid cross domain policy. For this, you can "http-server" or a server of your choice.
4. The working version of the "runDemo" function should look like this:

```js
function runDemo() {
 var doc = document.getElementById("purchase-order").contentDocument;
 var lineItems = doc.getElementsByTagName("lineItem");
 var html = "<table><tr><th>lineItems</th><th>firstprice</th></tr>";
 
 for (i = 0; i < lineItems.length; i++) {
  html += "<tr><td>" 
  + lineItems[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue 
  + "</td><td>" 
  + lineItems[i].getElementsByTagName("price")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue 
  + "</td></tr>";
 }
 html += "</table>";
 
 document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = html;
}
```

Comment: thanks. I don't want to run it on a server  and if you look at the link that I provided the code works fine without using it through a server. I have tried it myself....

Comment: the code actually works fine with "code block" but produce errors about cross domain when being used with an external xml file.